# Phonegap Android - admob zooms in

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I have searched for this answer for two days without success so I have to ask, here is my code.

```
package com.bbmbabes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.google.ads.*;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import org.apache.cordova.*;


public class BBMBabes extends DroidGap {
private static final String AdMob_Ad_Unit = "a15072ff10d80ef";
private AdView adView; 
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMob_Ad_Unit); 
    LinearLayout layout = super.root;
    layout.addView(adView); 
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(request); 
    super.loadUrl("http://bbmbabes.com/mobile.html");
    WebSettings ws = super.appView.getSettings();
    ws.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);

}

}
```

I have the app set to zoom density far and it works, but it also makes that Admob ad zoom out. When the ad changes to a new one it makes everything zoom in. Is there a way to set the zoom to affect only the website and not the ad?

Answer (score 0):

You can use iScroll it has a zooming feature for the div only.Although i haven't used it yet.

You can also give a try to Hammer.js,it has zooming features

This is a link where the person has implemented zooming using hammer
http://www.appliness.com/multitouch-with-hammer-js/